# Xcode crashes when trying to make a UI test that involves a webview

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, fastlane, fastlane-snapshot

Working on building an automatic UI test for a swift iOS app. The app involves a web-view for logging in with facebook. Every time tap within the bounds of the web-view and try to log into facebook it crashes Xcode if I am attempting to build the UI test using the built in Xcode UI recording.  It does not matter if I use my iPhone 6 or a simulator, no matter what Xcode will crash.

I am using Xcode 9. And the FBSDKLoginKit and FBSDKCoreKit.

Steps to reproduce:

1) Have an app with a webview

2) Hit record UI test

3) Click anywhere within the bounds of the webview

Is there a reason for this behavior?

Are there settings in Xcode I need to change in order to record web-view interactions?

Below is the error message I get when Xcode crashes.

```
Process:               Xcode [70544]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               9.3 (14154)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-14154000000000000~2
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       826408812
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [70544]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2018-05-21 14:04:50.053 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.4 (17E199)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        335CE1E7-B5AB-F717-E6D0-019AF52B3708

Sleep/Wake UUID:       7824F1AB-C514-4609-A447-F15EA9C86C84

Time Awake Since Boot: 99000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1800 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        18  Dispatch queue: XCUIRecorder_iOS.processingQueue

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 9E145
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): First snapshot has type Other: Other, 0x7f9d8c64aaf0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0}}
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: 

Backtrace:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3   +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4   -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] (in Foundation)
  5   +[XCUIRecorderNodeFinder nodeToFindElementForSnapshots:language:platform:] (in XCTest)
  6   -[XCUIRecorderUtilities nodeToFindElementForSnapshots:] (in XCTest)
  7   __177-[XCUIRecorder_iOS _XCT_recordedEventNames:timestamp:duration:startLocation:startElementSnapshot:startApplicationSnapshot:endLocation:endElementSnapshot:endApplicationSnapshot:]_block_invoke (in XCTest)
  8   _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
  9   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 10   _dispatch_queue_serial_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 11   _dispatch_queue_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 12   _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh (in libdispatch.dylib)
 13   _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread (in libdispatch.dylib)
 14   _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 15   start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)

ëØ$ïˇˇ
abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
NSInternalInconsistencyException
```

Comment: Same thing happening to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an Xcode bug to me. You can report it on the [Apple Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com/web/).

Comment: According to Apple Forums https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/98038 "Recording UI test involving WKWebView crashes Xcode", that person reported a bug https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=38190991, however, Apple doesn't allow you to view bugs... So, maybe its been reported, maybe its being looked into, maybe not...